# Header background color issue

Tags: css

Would you know I can't see the white background color of my header? For some reason I can only see the background image used as body background. Thks

```
body { 
overflow: hidden; 
background:url(../images/81107173.jpg) no-repeat center fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-ms-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;} 

#header {position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; height:100px; overflow:hidden; background-color:#FFF; }

#container {position:absolute; top:100px; bottom:60px; left:0px; overflow:auto; background:#639;}

#footer {position:absolute; bottom:0px; height:60px; left:0px; overflow:hidden; background:#FC6;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `overflow:hidden;` and no width defined. I don't see any of your HTML either so I don't know if you have content in the header div.

Add a width to your header and you should at least see the white background. E.g.

```
#header {
   /* all your current css */
   width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks - width was indeed the issue. With 100% it works OK now.

Comment: Awesome & obviously you can adjust the width accordingly to your needs, but I used 100% to give you the full width.